# Weird behavior with RequestParameter() and QueryParameter()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm kind of stumped here. Does anyone know why `RequestParameter()` and/or `QueryParameter()`wouldn't retrieve a query string variable?

Here's my URL that the page lands on

`https://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707dfbbf4acecff6ddf414f6180642add47372461b01f396a937&mobileNumber=19186916096&programId=cf4b0e7c-8c4e-4254-b758-0634532b1703`

Then, I've got basic AMPScript code

`set @programId = RequestParameter("programId")`

I've tried both QueryParameter and RequestParameter. For some reason, I cannot output the `@programId` (it's just blank). This is so straight forward, I'm curious is anyone aware of any weird instances where this might not work as expected?

If it matters, I'm dynamically building an `<input type='submit'>` element and have a `formaction` attribute whose value is the URL that the page lands on. This is within an outside, parent form. So from my knowledge, specifying `formaction` within an input submit element basically overrides the parent form action and it does, hence my landed URL is what I specified in the input element.

Comment: I've tested this and it works for me. Must be related to your form action. Please can you share a code snippet of your form element? And what exactly do you mean by an " outside parent form"?

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment.  I posted a more detailed version of this question at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224910/posting-to-a-form-query-string-variable-is-not-being-picked-up