# Posting to a form, query string variable is not being picked up

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm writing up a landing page in Marketing Cloud.  The idea is that, for simplicities sake, the page would be able to re-activate a paused automation.  So, here's my dashboard:

[image]

Each of the "Activate" buttons to the right are dynamically created via SSJS.  Here's the code:

```
Write("<td><input type='submit' name='submitActivate' value='Activate' formmethod='post' formaction='https://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707dfbbf4acecff6ddf414f6180642add47372461b01f396a937&mobileNumber=" + Variable.GetValue("@mobileNumber") + "&programId=" + Result[i].ObjectID + "'></input></td>");
```

I'm posting to the same URL as the landing page, but I'm passing in "ProgramID" as a query string variable.  When I click on "Activate" on one of these records, the posted URL is:

[image]

Notice the ProgramID is now in the URL as expected.  The problem I'm having is I cannot get RequestParameter() or even QueryParameter() to pick this value up.  The beginning of the landing page is:

[image]

When I output this AMPScript variable to the page, I get nothing.  Here's the output code:

[image]

And finally, here's the UI output:

[image]

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why my page is not picking this variable up.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried moving programID in front of mobileNumber to see if it displays there.  Also, I am assuming the value in the Program ID cell in your table comes from the same JSON? So that `Result[i].ObjectID` definitely has a value?